# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am getting `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`after upgrading the Jersey distribution. I've registered the `MultiPart` in the `web.xml` but it seems like I am missing more to configure.

pom

```
<!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey Spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.client.rest.service</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.contextPath</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsps/rest</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
  <param-value>/(resources|(WEB-INF/jsp))/.*</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Code:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.createResource( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.ALSB_DOCUSIGN_ADDRESS )
                + ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_SEND_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS ) );

        Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget
                .path( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_SEND_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS ) )
                .request( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
                .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, docSb )
                .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, DocusignRESTContants.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
                .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) );

        Response response = builder.post( Entity.entity( multiPart, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM ), Response.class );
```

stacktrace

```
Caused by:   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart.
```

Comment: Please also show the _code_ that is causing this error

Comment: @peeskillet. There are so many layers but the code fails right on the post method where I am trying to send the octet stream as a media type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I am sending the form as MultiPart object t be able to send multiple forms. I had to send it as a byte stream not just as a plain java object. `multipart.toString().getBytes()` in the entity method. I am getting 200 status code back from the vendor.